# Windows 8.1 doesn't allow me to update device drivers manually

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1

I'm trying to unlock my htc's bootloader and my computer is being a jackass about it. I'm doing my best to fix the ''waiting for device'' error - so basically I have a problem with the driver of my phone. Windows does not allow me to update the device's drivers with my own driver and the one that it chooses automatically does not solve any problems either. When I try to choose a driver from ''Have disk..'', it says the device's drivers are already up to date.

I read that this is a common problem and since I don't have win 8.1 pro, then I can't solve it through local group policy editor, either.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Right Click to HTC device and select update driver software.
3. Browse my computer for driver software.
4. Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.
5. Show all devices.
6. Click Have Disk.
7. Select the folder that contains driver `.inf` file.
8. Proceed to continue.

See if you get the same result with this way. Also check driver version and date from device manager and within the `.inf` file.